# Rename multiple file upload codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to rename all files during uploading process. I'm uploading 3 files at single time. My frontend code is

```
<form>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo_1">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="pan_1">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="add_1">
</form>
```

My code in controller is as following

```
function upload(){
    $this->upload_file('photo_1');
     $this->upload_file('pan_1');
     $this->upload_file('add_1');
}
function upload_file($field_name)
    {

        //$ext = substr( strrchr($_FILES[$field_name]['name'], '.'), 1);
        //$new_name = $types.'_'.$numb.'_dev_.'.$ext;
        $config['file_name']            = $_FILES[$field_name]['name'];
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
       // $config['max_size']             = 100;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
        {
            return array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        }
    }
```

But I' getting same name for each file with increment. **Like photo_1, photo_11, photo_12**. I want file name like **photo_sometext_1**

any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `$config['file_name'] = $_FILES[$field_name]['name'];`. You need pass the desired file name.

OR

Good approach is to create `encrypt_name` for each file. This way codeigniter will create random name for each file uploaded.

See this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences document for see the available options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['file_name'] = "sometext".$_FILES[$field_name]['name'].;
```

If you want to rename it entirely you need to capture the  extension and append it to the name you want to give.

Will look like

```
$config['file_name'] =" some text".$extension
```

`$extension` is your files extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing following line in my controller just below

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
```